# Apostrophe-cms Unable login to localhost:3000 after install

Tags: node.js, authentication, apostrophe-cms

I am a beginner in Apostrophe-cms. I tried to follow installation environment Apostrophe, until the step node app.js. I can run the web on localhost:3000, but could not login.

These are the steps which I do:

CMD show when I created new user

[image: CMD show when i created new user]

when I run node app.js
[image: when i run node app.js]
Then I can open the website:

However, I could not login

I tried input user name: admin, password: admin. And I tried to run the code to create new user: admin1 / admin1, but still the same. When I click Login button the page do not login.

Could you help me on this? Did I missing any step? Or any suggestion ?

I tried to install on Mac Book and Windows and removed and installed several times but the same thing. L

Comment: Your have a space before **add** in **apostrophe-users: add** make sure there's no space. The second error is quite obvious, you have to add a secret for sessions to work. In the lib directory there's apostrophe-express directory which should contain a file index.js there should be a variable **secret** if it's empty type something in, it can be anything

Comment: I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

Molda's answer is correct. Molda, you should submit that as an answer so that DanielBarbarian can accept it. The space after the : is the problem, like Molda says. The message about the secret can be ignored as a warning for now but Molda's response about it is valid as to what you should do.

Comment: Fixed!! Thank you so much.